# ADO.net Entity Data Model Does Not Exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**I use VS2019 Version 16.11.5 .**

**I Create Web Project With .Net 5**

[image]

**In Add New Item->Data can not find ADO or...**

[image]

**I installed Ef6**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

EntityFramework Core doesn't use the "EDMX" data model designers, it is purely code-first.

If you want to scaffold a database context from an existing database or create a new model and use migrations to create and update databases, you could see this page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

using NUGET Add the package EntityFrameworkCore, you can add it runing in NuGet console the next comands

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: The question is not about EF Core

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).